# localhost redirecionou-o demasiadas vezes

Tags: java, jsf, jpa, spring-security

Boa tarde, estou tentando direcionar um usuário do sistema para uma pagina de erro caso algo de errado aconteça com a sessão ou caso o usuário tenha acesso negado a determinada pagina etc…

Estou utilizando o Spring Security para isso.

na minha classe applicationContext.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="appUserDetailsService" class="security.AppUserDetailsService" />

    <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="jsfAccessDeniedHandler"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsfAccessDeniedHandler" class="security.JsfAccessDeniedHandler">
        <beans:property name="loginPath" value="/AcessoNegado.xhtml" />
        <beans:property name="contextRelative" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="security.JsfLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/Login.xhtml"/>
        <beans:property name="redirectStrategy" ref="jsfRedirectStrategy" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="jsfRedirectStrategy" class="security.JsfRedirectStrategy"/>

    <http pattern="/Login.xhtml" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/Erro.xhtml" security="none"/>
    <http pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" security="none" />

    <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true">
        <custom-filter ref="exceptionTranslationFilter" before="FILTER_SECURITY_INTERCEPTOR"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/Home.xhtml" access="isAuthenticated()" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/marca/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/agenda/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/cliente/**" access="hasAnyRole('PADRAO','ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/usuario/**" access="hasAnyRole('ADMINISTRADORES')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />

        <form-login login-page="/Login.xhtml" authentication-failure-url="/Login.xhtml?invalid=true" default-target-url="/" always-use-default-target="true"/>

        <logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" invalidate-session="true" />

    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="appUserDetailsService">
            <!-- <password-encoder hash="md5"/> -->
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

E usei como modelo essas 3 classes apresentadas no curso da algaworks.

https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/ResolvendoProblemaRequisicaoAjax/src/main/java/com/algaworks/pedidovenda/security/JsfAccessDeniedHandler.java

https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/ResolvendoProblemaRequisicaoAjax/src/main/java/com/algaworks/pedidovenda/security/JsfLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint.java

https://github.com/algaworks/curso-javaee-primefaces/blob/master/ResolvendoProblemaRequisicaoAjax/src/main/java/com/algaworks/pedidovenda/security/JsfRedirectStrategy.java

Aparentemente o usuário é sim direcionado para a pagina de erro que criei conforme mostrado na url, porem essa pagina nao abre.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: é a primeira vez que utilizo o Spring, alguma ideia de como resolver?

att;

Edd: Verificando o console do chrome percebi as seguintes situacoes. quando devo ser direcionado para a pagina de erro /AcessoNegado.xhtml existem varias requisicoes e entre uma delas existe uma falha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]